# Magento2: Layered Navigation show Negative Price Filter

Tags: magento2.3, layered-navigation, data-migration-tool

After migrating from  M1.9 to M2.3.1.
Layered Navigation Shows Negative price range

[image]

I remove all Negative prices manually. After that layered navigation filter shows the correct range and doesn't show the negative price range.

[image]

But after running the commands :

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
```

All Negative values reverted and layered navigation show the Negative price range.
Why this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Configurable products have redundant prices that cause wrong configurable min_price calculation.

To see the count of all configurable products prices records from the database:

`SELECT count(*) FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal WHERE entity_id in (SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity c where c.type_id = 'configurable');`

**Please backup your database before executing the query below!!!**

To resolve, delete the price records from the database:

`DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal WHERE entity_id in (SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity c where c.type_id = 'configurable');`

Then run the following commands which will update the catalog_product_index_price table:

`bin/mage index:reindex`
`bin/mage cache:clean`

Run the following to check for negative product prices:

`select * from catalog_product_index_price where min_price < 0;`